# Clip Property CSS values

Tags: html, css, clip

After trying a gruesome lot of time I am still not gaining the correct co-ordinates or pixels to clip/crop out my image

the image:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4L2T.jpg

I want to clip out the right and left white portion of the image.Thanks.

Comment: What's your CSS and HTML?

Comment: I am currently using it on shopify platform with liquid codes

Comment: Just using this property

Comment: img {
    position: absolute;
    clip:rect(0px,60px,200px,0px);
} I tried various combinations still ain't working

Comment: What browser are you in?

Comment: Why couldn't you just pull the image into paint or something and remove the white??

Comment: I can't do I am working on an e-commerce start up with thousands of images being uploaded daily directly to the website.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Is this what your wanting? The clip property does **NOT CHANGE THE IMAGE SIZE!**

```css
img {    
    position: absolute;
    clip: rect(58px 416px 532px 184px);
}
body {
  background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4L2T.jpg">
```

I really think this is what you want:

```css
div {
    position: relative;
    height: 475px;
    width: 234px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
img {    
    position: absolute;
    left: -183px;
    top: -58px;
}
```

```html
<div>
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4L2T.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me out.No wonder the community downvotes you even for your help.

Comment: If this is your solution, please mark this as answer. If not, please explain why this is not your solution.